# How to feed LSTM when training data is in multiple csv files of time series of different length?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am running an LSTM to classify medical recordings for each patient. That's being said, for each patient (an observation) I have one CSV file. The whole dataset is multiple CSV files, each one of them is DataFrame of time series. ***This is not that obvious cuz there is one small difference between feeding LSTM with images and time series, it's the SIZE of sequences. CNN assumes the inputs have the same size but here we have inputs with different length***

**Question:**

***How to feed LSTM in this case?***

I am sure if you are familiar with image classification you can help with my question but it's not just the same approach.

**Example**

For one patient I have a DataFrame that has all the recording I want to use in my LSTM.

```
df.shape
Out[29]: (5679000, 4) 
# The 5679000 change from one patient to another but 4 columns are fixed
```

Have a look here:

```
df.head(4)

Out[30]: 

   AIRFLOW     SaO2    ECG  Target  
0    -34.0  31145.0  304.0     0.0  
1    -75.0  31145.0  272.0     0.0  
2    -63.0  31145.0  254.0     0.0  
3    -57.0  31145.0  251.0     1.0  
4    -60.0  31145.0  229.0     0.0
```

**Problem:**

Any suggestions to feed my network?

Comment: What is your issue? This code is a little confusing. If each of your data points has a variable number of time steps, your batch size needs to be 1, so you need to train this in mini batches, not all at once. That is, unless you can group patients who have the same number of timesteps or fix the number of timesteps. Also, why are you using the batch size as the number of cells in the first LSTM?

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia what you are asking is exactly what I am trying to figure out! the mini_batches, batch_size, ... how to do it correctly? any suggestions for improvement will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since your data points have variable sequence lengths, you can't easily train your network all at once. Instead, you must train in mini batches of size 1 or fix your sequence length, although the latter probably doesn't make sense based on the data you're dealing with.

Take a look at the Keras function [train_on_batch](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#train_on_batch). Using this, you can train your model using each individual patient, although using a batch size of 1 has its own [issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316464/how-does-batch-size-affect-convergence-of-sgd-and-why).

As for the model, I would suggest using the [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). If you want to try something simple, just use an input sequence of variable length and a feature size of `3`. This should give you a baseline, which is what I assume you want from your function name. Something like this:

```
input_ = Input(shape=(None, 3))
x = LSTM(128)(input_)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input_, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of different length sequences, you have two main approaches that I know of:

1- train your model with a batch size of 1 which is not ideal due to how much time it takes and by consequence the resources it requires.

2- you could determine the longest sequence, use that length as your batch size, add padding values to the other sequences and ignore those padding values during the training of your model.

Answer (score -4):

`lstm_baseline(df[['AIRFLOW','SaO2','ECG']], df['Target'], 64)`

Comment: what 64 is referring to?

Comment: You answer is pretty abvious! That's for one patient not all the training data !

Comment: 64 is your batch_size.

Comment: I don't think you can train this LSTM on multiple patients. Here the network take into account some previous values of your data columns, for making predictions. but does it make sense to use data from one patient for the next one?